# Custom sorting google scripts

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to ask if it is possible to sort the data sheet with one row but from a modified sort. The sorting should be

1. Empty cells
2. Accepted
3. In Progress
4. For Follow up

This is the custom order we need. These options are from a dropdown on the spreadsheet. How can I do this on google scripts for google spreadsheet? Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Here is my code below:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var currentRow = e.range.getRow();
var archiverow = e.source.getSheetByName("Archive").getLastRow();
Logger.log(archiverow)
Logger.log(currentRow)
var new_id = archiverow + currentRow
var id = "AR-"+new_id;
Logger.log(id);

var name = e.namedValues["Your Name"];
SendAdminSlack(e, name);
var duedate = e.namedValues["Due Date"].toString();
s.getRange(currentRow, 13).setValue(duedate);
duedate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(duedate), "GMT+8", "MMMMM dd, yyyy");

var date_submitted = s.getRange(currentRow, 2).getValue().toString().split(' ');
date_submitted = date_submitted[1] + " " +  date_submitted[2] + " " + date_submitted[3];
date_submitted = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_submitted), "GMT+8", "MMMMM dd, yyyy");

var sum = s.getRange(currentRow, 3).getValue();
var description = e.namedValues["Request Description"];

var ovcalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var title = '[ADMIN REQUEST] ' + name;

var caldesc = "Summary: " + sum + "\n";
caldesc += "Due Date: " + duedate + "\n\n";
caldesc += "Description: " + description;
Logger.log(caldesc);

var event = ovcalendar.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(duedate), {description: caldesc});
Logger.log(date_submitted.toString())
s.getRange(currentRow, 14).setValue(event.getId().toString())
s.getRange(currentRow, 1).setValue(id);

var subj = "Admin Request for "+name;
var message = "Request Id: "+id+"<br>";
message += "Due Date: "+duedate+"<br>";
message += "Request Summary: "+sum+"<br><br>";
message += "Request Description: "+description;

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: kath,
  subject: subj,
  htmlBody: message,
  noReply: true
});

s.sort(9); // I NEED TO CUSTOMIZE THIS SORT OR MAKE A NEW ONE
```

I need to sort it specifically on the order above the code.

Comment: yes. take a look at spreadsheetApp and show code attempts and whats not working per s.o. question guidelines

Comment: can you show the link of this custom sort of yours?

Comment: in s.o. you have to take a look at the docs and produce some code first. then tell us what's not working.

Comment: the sort in spreadsheet api only have sort and sort(row, ascending). it doesn't comply in what i need to do.

Comment: spreadsheetApp is not for sorting, ita for getting values and saving. use any javascript sorting in between like the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

generically sorting an array by specific value:

```
var cond = function(term) {
    var score, conditions = ["For Follow Up", "In Progress", "Accepted"];
    if (term == "") {
        score = conditions.length;
    } else {
        score = conditions.indexOf(term);
    }

    return score;
}


// perhaps it's this simple
var values = s.getValues();

values = values.sort(function(a, b){

var column = 0; // or wherever your value is

    return (cond(a[column]) < cond(b[column])) ? -1 : (cond(a[column]) > cond(b[column])) ? 1 : 0;

});

s.setValues(values); // maybe, your need maybe more complicated.
```

All typed on a phone so consider it pseudocode in the main

Comment: didnt work for me man. it said InternalError: Cannot convert function (a, b) { return (cond(a) < cond(b)) ? -1 : (cond(a) > cond(b)) ? 1 : 0; } to (class).

Comment: Typing answers on the phone catches me out sometimes. As I said generic answer. `values.sort` follows you getting them from your range `s`. Putting the values back in the range is straightforward.

Comment: Super helpful thanks for the high level. I just returned the equivalent of `cond(a) - cond(b)` in my `.sort`'s compare function but the custom `cond` + `.getValues` + `.setValues` was great for leveraging javascript to custom sort order things.